# Coin flip app mistake in code (Java)

Tags: java, android

I have tried to make this app where the coin flips on the click of the button. Everything seems to be right but when I run it on my Android, It doesn't show the picture from Imageview and it crashes after a few button clicks.
Can someone see what is wrong in this code?
I have already checked are the images in right location, and their names.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bt1;
    ImageView nov;
    int strana;
    Random r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        nov = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.novcic);
        r = new Random();

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                strana = r.nextInt(2);

                if (strana == 0) {
                    nov.setImageResource(R.drawable.pismo);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pismo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (strana == 1) {
                    nov.setImageResource(R.drawable.glava);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Glava!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does logcat show?

Comment: I think you'll need to show your xml layout for this activity and provide the error message from the crash as @Sweeper stated above.

Comment: There are no errors in Android Studio, no red wavy lines

Comment: What is in your Logcat window in Android Studio?  Or - from the command line: adb logcat